# Possible to checkout a file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that inserts webparts onto a page.  The problem is that if I don't have the page checked out it will throw the following error:

> Exception calling "AddWebPart" with "3" argument(s): "The file is not
>   checked out.  You must first check out this document before making
>   changes." At C:\temp\AddWebParts.ps1:49 char:27

Is it possible to checkout a page using PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this after doing a little more research:

```
$Site = Get-SPWeb $siteurl
$Site.GetFile($myFile).CheckOut()
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

yes, if you have SPListItem, you may call

```
$file = $listItem.File;
$file.CheckOut();
```

Comment: Thanx! This works great. How do you check in the same file again?

Answer (score 2):

I think the POSH script excerpts above (by Abe & Ashish) would work but also verify the CheckOut & Lock status property of the file prior to checking it out: $fooFile.CheckOutType - this returns enum type showing online, offline & none.
To check the file property LockType - $fooFile.LockType which returns enum SPLockType (exclusive, shared & none).

Comment: `The code will be similar to the following:  
1. $fooWeb = Get-SPWeb("FooWebURL");
2. $fooFile = $fooWeb.GetFile("FooFile");
3. if($fooFile.CheckOutType -eq "None" -And $fooFile.LockType -eq "None")
4. { $fooFile.CheckOut()
5.       Write-Host $fooFile.Name Checked out
6. } else 
7.  {    Write-Host $fooFile.Name already Checked out or locked }
8. $fooWeb.Dispose()`

Answer (score 0):

Below script will help you to checkout file

```
$urlWeb = "http://mysite"
$urlWebWP =  "http://mysite/pages/default.aspx"

$web = Get-SPWeb 
$urlWeb $page =  $web.GetFile($urlWebWP)
$page.CheckOut()
```