# SPLimitedWebPartManager throwing "File is not checked out" error on AddWebPart and DeleteWebPart

Tags: web-part, powershell

I'm writing a powershell function to add custom webparts (i.e. not Out Of The Box webparts such as ContentEditor) to publishing pages on a SharePoint Server 2010 site. I encountered a frustrating issue when trying to add / delete webparts from the page whereby SPLimitedWebPartManager was throwing the following error:

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    -- Error information
    --------------------------------------------------
    Line Number: 198
    Offset: 27
    Command: 
    Line:                   $wpManager.AddWebPart($wp, $WebPartSettings.Zone, $WebPartSettings.ZoneIndex)
    Error Details: Exception calling "AddWebPart" with "3" argument(s): "The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes."
    Unbound args: 
    Exception: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "AddWebPart" with "3" argument(s): "The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes." ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes.
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.SaveSomeChanges(SPLayoutProperties layoutProperties)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.MakeSpaceForWebPart(WebPart webPartToPlace, Int32 zoneIndex, String zoneID, Boolean storeInPendingChangesList)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnWebPartAddingCore(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex, Boolean throwIfLocked)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex)
       at AddWebPart(Object , Object[] )
       at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
```

I have `Write-Host` statements on the line before calling `$wpManager.AddWebPart` and `$wpManager.DeleteWebPart` that print out the values of `CheckedOutBy`, `CheckOutStatus`, etc for the PublishingPage that show that the file is checked out but I still get an error stating that the file is *not* checked out.

I found this post:

[Possible to checkout a file using PowerShell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25376/possible-to-checkout-a-file-using-powershell)

but their issue was the file wasn't actually checked out, whereas mine apparently is checked out.

Sample output from `Write-Host` here:

```
    CheckOutType: Online
    CheckOutStatus: LongTerm
    CheckedOutBy: MYDOMAIN\user.name
```

On another question, Anders Rask suggested the poster compare the userid of the `PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckedOutBy` field with the userid of `PublishingPage.Web.CurrentUser` but these returned the exact same value.

My PowerShell code is:

```
    function Add-WebPartToPage

        Param
        (
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$SpWeb,
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage]$PublishingPage,
            [System.Xml.XmlNode]$WebPartSettings,
            [string]$LogName
        )
        Process
        {
            if ($PublishingPage -eq $null)
            {
                Write-Host "Cannot add webparts to page as page is null"
                return
            }

            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PublishingPage.Url))
            {
                Write-Host "Unable to access webparts for page as page url is undefined"
                return
            }

            Try
            {
                $serverRelativeUrl = $SpWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $PublishingPage.Url
                Write-Host "ServerRelativeUrl:" $serverRelativeUrl

                [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager]$wpManager = $SpWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager($serverRelativeUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
                if ($wpManager -eq $null)
                {
                    Write-Host "Failed to retrieve WPManager"
                    return
                }

                # Page must be checked out before making any changes
                if ($PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType -eq "None")
               {
                    Write-Host "checking out file" $PublishingPage.Title
                   $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOut()
               }

                $pageWebparts = $wpManager.WebParts

                if ($pageWebparts -eq $null -or $pageWebparts.Count -eq 0)
                {
                    Write-Host "No webparts on page " $PublishingPage.Name
                }
                else
                {
                    $pageWebparts | ForEach-Object {
                        Write-Host "Webpart:" $_.Name
                    }

                    $existingWebPart = $pageWebparts | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $WebPartSettings.Name }

                    if ($existingWebPart -ne $null)
                    {
                        $file = $PublishingPage.ListItem.File
                        Write-Host "Checked out by" $file.CheckedOutBy
                        Write-Host "Current user:" $file.Web.CurrentUser
                        Write-Host "Locked by:" $file.LockedByUser
                        Write-Host "LockType:" $file.LockType
                        Write-Host "Removing webpart from page..."
                        #$wpManager.DeleteWebPart($existingWebPart)
                    }
                }           

                Write-Host "CheckOutType:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType
                Write-Host "CheckOutStatus:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus
                Write-Host "CheckedOutBy:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckedOutBy

                Write-Host "Adding webpart"

                [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$oxmlReader = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($WebPartSettings.FileLocation)

                [string]$errorMsg = ""
                $wp = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($oxmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg)
                Write-Host "Import output:" $errorMsg

                $wpManager.AddWebPart($wp, $WebPartSettings.Zone, $WebPartSettings.ZoneIndex)

                $PublishingPage.CheckIn("Added webpart")
            }
            Catch
            {
                Write-Host $Error[0]

                if ($PublishingPage -ne $null -and $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType -ne "none")
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Error occurred whilst adding webparts to the page. Undoing checkout"
                    $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.UndoCheckOut()
                }

                throw $Error[0]
            }       
        }
    }
```

NOTE: The $WebPartSettings comes from an XML config file

```
    <webpart name="MyWebPart.webpart" zone="Header" zoneIndex="0" FileLocation="C:\Releases\MyWebPart\MyWebPart.webpart">
    </webpart>
```

Comment: Same problem as: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42720/removing-orphaned-webparts-via-powershell-checkin-checkout-requirement-loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem turned out to be *where* I was checking out the page. The page must be checked out *before* the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` is retrieved.

```
function Add-WebPartToPage

    Param
    (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$SpWeb,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage]$PublishingPage,
        [System.Xml.XmlNode]$WebPartSettings,
        [string]$LogName
    )
    Process
    {
        if ($PublishingPage -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Host "Cannot add webparts to page as page is null"
            return
        }

        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PublishingPage.Url))
        {
            Write-Host "Unable to access webparts for page as page url is undefined"
            return
        }

        Try
        {
            $serverRelativeUrl = $SpWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $PublishingPage.Url
            Write-Host "ServerRelativeUrl:" $serverRelativeUrl

            # Page must be checked out before making any changes
            if ($PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType -eq "None")
           {
                Write-Host "checking out file" $PublishingPage.Title
               $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOut()
           }

           [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager]$wpManager = $SpWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager($serverRelativeUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
            if ($wpManager -eq $null)
            {
                Write-Host "Failed to retrieve WPManager"
                return
            }

            $pageWebparts = $wpManager.WebParts

            if ($pageWebparts -eq $null -or $pageWebparts.Count -eq 0)
            {
                Write-Host "No webparts on page " $PublishingPage.Name
            }
            else
            {
                $pageWebparts | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host "Webpart:" $_.Name
                }

                $existingWebPart = $pageWebparts | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $WebPartSettings.Name }

                if ($existingWebPart -ne $null)
                {
                    $file = $PublishingPage.ListItem.File
                    Write-Host "Checked out by" $file.CheckedOutBy
                    Write-Host "Current user:" $file.Web.CurrentUser
                    Write-Host "Locked by:" $file.LockedByUser
                    Write-Host "LockType:" $file.LockType
                    Write-Host "Removing webpart from page..."
                    #$wpManager.DeleteWebPart($existingWebPart)
                }
            }          

            Write-Host "CheckOutType:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType
            Write-Host "CheckOutStatus:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutStatus
            Write-Host "CheckedOutBy:" $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckedOutBy

            Write-Host "Adding webpart"

            [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$oxmlReader = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($WebPartSettings.FileLocation)

            [string]$errorMsg = ""
            $wp = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($oxmlReader, [ref]$errorMsg)
            Write-Host "Import output:" $errorMsg

            $wpManager.AddWebPart($wp, $WebPartSettings.Zone, $WebPartSettings.ZoneIndex)

            $PublishingPage.CheckIn("Added webpart")
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Host $Error[0]

            if ($PublishingPage -ne $null -and $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOutType -ne "none")
            {
                Write-Verbose "Error occurred whilst adding webparts to the page. Undoing checkout"
                $PublishingPage.ListItem.File.UndoCheckOut()
            }

            throw $Error[0]
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of other bogus fixes on the web which claim to fix this problem, but thumbs up, this seems to be only one that does the trick.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely Correct.