# using powershell script update the page name in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I wan to change the page name with Power shell script. When I had run the script
I was given an spexception error:

> Exception calling "CheckOut" with "0" argument(s): "The URL
>   'en/articles/kbarticles/Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing.aspx' is invalid.
>   It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file
>   or folder that is not in the current Web." At line:1 char:1 +
>   $spFile.CheckOut() + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified:
>   (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   SPException

The below script was used for update the name of the page:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("here i am given the web url")
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("full url with page name")
$spFile.CheckOut("Online",$null)    ////here i am getting the error(spexception)
$spFile.Properties["Name"] = "Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing_New"
$spFile.Update()
$spFile.CheckIn("Update page layout via PowerShell",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but i am run the script same as your updates.Still i am getting the same error(Spexception)

Comment: Exception calling "CheckOut" with "0" argument(s): "The URL
'en/articles/kbarticles/Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing.aspx' is invalid.  It may
refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that
is not in the current Web."
At line:1 char:1
+ $spFile.CheckOut()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException

Comment: the above exception was i am facing

Comment: when i had run the script by power shell $spFile.CheckOut()

Comment: Please see my updated answer below

Answer (score 3):

`Get-SPWeb` does not need to have "(" and ")" around the parameters. Try:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "web url"
```

also, use `$spFile.CheckOut()` without any parameters.

Full script:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "here i am given the web url"
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("full url with page name")
$spFile.CheckOut()
$spFile.Properties["Name"] = "Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing_New"
$spFile.Update()
$spFile.CheckIn("Update page layout via PowerShell",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Also, take a look at [this similar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25376/possible-to-checkout-a-file-using-powershell) question, specifically the part about checking if the page is in a state that allows it to be checked out (Pseudo code cited from a comment on that question):

> ```
> $fooWeb = Get-SPWeb("FooWebURL");
> $fooFile = $fooWeb.GetFile("FooFile");
>
> if($fooFile.CheckOutType -eq "None" -And $fooFile.LockType -eq "None")
> { 
>     $fooFile.CheckOut()
>     Write-Host $fooFile.Name Checked out 6.
> } 
> else 
> { 
>     Write-Host $fooFile.Name already Checked out or locked 
> } 
>
> $fooWeb.Dispose()
> ```

**Update after Error message was posted**

To use the `$spWeb.GetFile()` you must specify a FULL, existing URL to the file, which you are not providing right now!

It should look something like `http://siteadress/possiblysubweb/Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing.aspx`, so you are missing part of the url.

Comment: $spFile.CheckOut() should do the trick.

Comment: Yepp, that feels like the real error :)

Comment: $spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("http://collabsl-sp13:2009/en/articles/kbarticles/Pages/R2-1_articles_Testing.aspx") this is the full URL i am given

Comment: seems you are missing the http:// or https:// part? Also what URL are you using in Get-SPWeb? Should be http(s)://collabsl-sp13:2009/en/articles/kbarticles